# laravel proplem with Model::with appended column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-query-builder

i try to add appended column with Model::with

```
$pitchChech =  Pitch::with(['prices'=>function ($query){
            $query->select('*',\DB::Raw("(select sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(valid_to ,valid_from))) from pitch_price as xpitch_price where pitch_id = pitch_price.pitch_id ) as x "))
            ->whereRaw(" x < ?",[24]);
        }])->get();
      dd($pitchChech);
```

and i have this output

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'x' in 'where clause'
```

i can't understand what is the problem im using laravel 5.1 but i don't think there are problem with ut

Comment: change `->get()` to `->toSql()` and show result

Comment: when i change it toSql it just call Pitch model

Comment: `with()` is for loading relationships. Not for custom SQL. You may want to look at `addSelect`, `selectRaw`, `join`, etc instead.

Comment: i traid 
`$pitchChech = Pitch::whereHas('prices',function ($query){
            $query->select("*",\DB::Raw("(select sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(valid_to ,valid_from))) from pitch_price as xpitch_price where pitch_id = pitch_price.pitch_id ) as total_h"))
                ->where("total_h","<", "24");
        })->get();`
and it still give me the same error

Comment: @AJamal, how about we start over, and you post your schema, models, and outline what it is you're trying to extract?

Answer (score 0):

For derived columns you have to use `having()`:

```
->having('x', '<', 24)
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'x' in 'having clause'

Comment: Please post the whole query.

Comment: it all the query

Comment: What code are you executing? The query from your question with `having()` instead of `where()`?